# Java - Send a UDP broadcast to the whole network, but not to self

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am trying to make a peer discovery solution between Android devices and Windows computers. I just a method of "broadcast and wait for responses". My problem is that the app which broadcasts the message also waits for responses **AT THE SAME TIME**.

It goes like this:

***THREAD A:*** Waits for a message, let's call it "X". When it receives an UDP packet, if the message is "X" it sends an UDP packet *BACK TO THE SENDER* (not broadcasting again), which we should call "Y".

***THERAD B:*** Broadcasts "X" all over the network. Then collects the addresses of all senders who replied with "Y".

Thread A and B run AT THE SAME TIME and cannot stop or pause each other.

When Thread B broadcasts X, Thread A (on the same device/computer) receives the message, therefore making a connection with .. itself.

Here is my current code:

```
public static void launchDiscovery () throws Exception 
    {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2005, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        while (true) {
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim(); 
//          if (message.equals("SMARTSHARE_REQUEST"))
//          if (message.equals("SMARTSHARE_REQUEST")&&!isTheSamePC(packet.getAddress())) //TODO fix here
            if (message.equals("SS_REQ") && !isTheSamePC(packet.getAddress())) //TODO fix here
            {
              byte[] sendData = "SS_RESP".getBytes();
              DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
              socket.send(sendPacket);
            }
          }

    }
    private static boolean isTheSamePC(InetAddress address) 
    {
        // Broadcast the message over all the network interfaces
        try
        {
          Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
          while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) 
          {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = (NetworkInterface) interfaces.nextElement();

            if (networkInterface.isLoopback() || !networkInterface.isUp()) {
              continue; // Don't want to broadcast to the loopback interface
            }

            for (InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) 
            {
                if (address.getHostAddress().equals(interfaceAddress.getAddress().getHostAddress()))
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How to avoid sending to self, without any third party APIs? This method works, but it's a bit slow and I want something faster too.

Comment: Obviously, you just have to ignore anything coming from yourself, either based on its source address or based on identity information encoded within.

Comment: That's the point. The "source address" method is kind of slow and the app has to loop through all network interfaces and get all IP's of the computer, because broadcasting is made to all network interfaces. This could be slow on some computers. What about identity information? How could this be done since the two threads are separate?

Comment: That's probably not your issue, but in the unlikely event that fetching the interfaces takes time, you could make it effectively instantaneous if you cached the list of addresses and interface *before* you started sending or checking received packets against it.  Likely the time is being spent elsewhere.  In terms of identity information, you just need a unique (enough) token.  Separate threads does not mean you cannot share data - it is especially easy with data established before they spin up.

Comment: What If I caught a list of the addresses before the app started, but the user has disconnected from WiFi for example, or switched networks? I think I will go for the token which is, I believe, the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

This seems like something that can be fixed with a little bit of logic. First, when receiving a packet make sure that the address is not from localhost, this can be achieved using

```
public boolean isFromPC(InetAddress address) {
    String rawAddress = address.toString();
    if(rawAddress.equals("/127.0.0.1")) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

This should do the trick. Now, if the "/" annoys you, you can simply do

```
String rawAddress = address.toString().substring(1);
```

And then do

```
rawAddress.equals("127.0.0.1");
```

This is normally what I do when comparing IP addresses by string, it works very well for me. Also, for broadcasting to all devices easily, you do not have to go through EVERY network interface, you can just get the subnet address and send the packet there. I am not exactly sure how you would do this, but you could check if it's correct by doing "ipconfig" in Windows Command Prompt and see if it's the same as your java code gave you.

Also, if you are working with domain names (such as google.com for example) you will get a result like this

```
google.com/173.194.115.39
```

To fix this, you can do

```
public String fixAddress(InetAddress address) {
    String rawAddress = address.toString(); // Do not use .substring(1) here!
    String[] addressList = rawAddress.split("/");
    if(addressList.length == 1) return addressList[0];
    else return addressList[1];
}
```

This way, you can make sure you are getting the raw address and not the domain if that situation ever happens to come up.

**IF YOU KNOW WHAT THE SPLIT METHOD DOES, YOU CAN IGNORE THIS!**

If you don't know what the split method is, it is a simple method where you can convert a string to an array by *splitting* it into pieces with a certain character/string and turns it into an array. Here is an example:

```
String rawGroceryList = "CHICKEN, CHEESE, MILK";
String[] groceryList = rawGroceryList.split(", "); // Convert the grocery list into an array

/* Now, lets print it out! */
System.out.println("-- START OF LIST --");
for(int i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Grocery #" + (i+1) + ": " + groceryList[i]);
}
System.out.println("--- END OF LIST ---");
```

**IF YOU KNOW WHAT SUBSTRINGS ARE, YOU CAN IGNORE THIS!**

If you don't know what the substring method does, it simply skips the amount of chars specified in the first argument. If you specify a second argument, it will start at the char you specify in the first argument and end at the char you specify in the second. Here is an example:

```
/* Skip first char */
String toTrim = "#Now let's look at this!"; // We do not want the hashtag!
String trimmedString = toTrim.substring(1); // It is now "Now let's look at this!"

/* Start at 3rd char and end at the string length subtracted by 3 */
String anotherTrim = "## HASHTAG ##"; // Oh no, more hashtags!
String anotherTrimmed = anotherTrim.substring(3, anotherTrim.length()-3); // Now it is "HASHTAG"

/* Print out results */
System.out.println(trimmedString);
System.out.println(anotherTrimmed);
```

Sorry for the long answer, I just wanted to make sure you knew what was happening. Oh, and no potato this time.

Answer (score 0):

You need compare the received packet with or local ips

Use this:

```
private boolean isLocalIP(InetAddress address) throws IOException {

    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface network = interfaces.nextElement();

        if (network.isLoopback() || ! network.isUp()) {
            continue;
        }

        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = network.getInetAddresses();
        while (inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress netAddress = inetAddresses.nextElement();

            if (address.getHostAddress().equals(netAddress.getHostAddress()))
                return true;

        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163482/8261085 is where I answered a similar issue. The answer allows an Android app to discover a server's IP address on the WiFi subnet for a given port value.  You just filter out your own broadcast from your listening socket.